# Pick a balance number of odd and even numbers in python

Tags: python, random

I need help please. I have this program.

```
col1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,13,16]
col2 = [2,4,5,6,7,9,11,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22] 
col3 = [7,8,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,23,24,25,27,29,30] 
col4 = [9,12,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,28,30,31,33] 
col5 = [20,21,24,25,26,28,30,32,33,34,35] 
b1 = [1,3,5,7,8] 
b2 = [2,4,6,7,9,10,11,12] 

def pickem():
    pick1 = random.choice(col1)
    pick2 = random.choice( [i for i in col2 if i > pick1] )
    pick3 = random.choice( [i for i in col3 if i > pick2] )
    pick4 = random.choice( [i for i in col4 if i > pick3] )
    pick5 = random.choice( [i for i in col5 if i > pick4] )

    bonus1 = random.choice(b1)
    bonus2 = random.choice(b2)

    return (pick1,pick2,pick3,pick4,pick5,bonus1,bonus2)

print( pickem() )
```

I would like the picked number to have a sum total of 3 odd numbers. Is there a way I can do that? It is choosing random numbers from the list I provided above but it will check to see how many of them are odd and if there are less than 3 or whatever amount I put it will pick again until there are 3 odd numbers in total, but only in col1 - col5. So though the final number are seven digits long, I only want to the first 5 digits to have a total of 3 odds. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide an example/desired output please?

Comment: What is the meaning of these numbers? Why are some of them skipped? Also - what approaches did you try to solve the problem? For example, if you just repeat the choosing code until the result meets the requirements, would that solve the problem? (Can you write code that checks whether the result has the right amount of odd numbers?)

Comment: The numbers are just some numbers I selected as a list of numbers I want the random function to pick from. that's why there are skips.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be drastically simplified if you use a list of lists for both the columns and the bonuses, rather than maintaining a separate variable for each list.

To generate the pick results, we pick a random number from the first list. Then, for every list after that, we slice off any element that is less than the element we picked last. Since the columns are sorted in ascending order, we can use the `bisect` module to efficiently find where to slice.

Finally, we check whether there's less than 3 odd numbers in our selected numbers. If there is, we repick all the numbers. If not, we move to selecting the bonus numbers.

The generation of the bonus results is similar to what you've done, but I've made it more concise using a list comprehension.

Here is the resulting code:

```py
import bisect
import random

columns = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,13,16],
    [2,4,5,6,7,9,11,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22], 
    [7,8,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,23,24,25,27,29,30],
    [9,12,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,28,30,31,33], 
    [20,21,24,25,26,28,30,32,33,34,35]
]

bonuses = [
    [1,3,5,7,8], 
    [2,4,6,7,9,10,11,12]
]

pick_results = []
while not pick_results:
    for column in columns:
        if not pick_results:
            pick_results.append(random.choice(column))
        else:
            pick_results.append(
                random.choice(column[bisect.bisect(column, pick_results[-1]):])
            )
    # Change to == 3 if you want there to be exactly 3 odd numbers.
    if sum(1 for item in pick_results if item % 2 == 1) < 3:
        pick_results = []
        
bonus_results = [random.choice(lst) for lst in bonuses]
print(tuple(pick_results) + tuple(bonus_results))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help BrokenBenchmark, and for the very clear explanation that you gave. I'm completely new to python so that was very helpful. However, it's not doing what I'd like it to do. Sometimes it returns 4 odds other times, 3 and other times 2 and sometimes 1. When you said 
# Change to == 3 if you want there to be exactly 3 odd numbers.
do you mean %2 == 3) < 3 or % 2 == 1) == 3? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yeah, use `LHS == 3` instead of `LHS < 3` in that case. The result appears to contain at least 3 odds for me -- I ran it 1000 times and wasn't able to find a case where it produced less than 3 odds.

Comment: By `LHS`, I mean left-hand-side (i.e. `sum(1 for item in pick_results if item % 2 == 1) == 3`)

Comment: I'm not sure why but for example the last time I ran it I got
(10, 19, 27, 30, 32, 1, 9) 2 odds
(1, 15, 16, 26, 28, 5, 7) 2 odds
(10, 15, 23, 25, 33, 7, 10) 4 odds
(13, 15, 25, 31, 32, 1, 9) 4 odds
(16, 19, 29, 31, 35, 8, 4) 4 odds
(2, 18, 19, 22, 24, 5, 9) 1 odd
These are the last 6 results I got back. Even when I changed it to == 3.
please help.

Comment: I was also wondering if I wanted to print more than one result with different number combinations how would I do that. In the way I had it I could print several different combinations at the same time. Is there a to do that with the structure you used? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Modulus Operator** to check if any given value is even or odd:

```
def is_even(value):
    if value % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The Modulus Operator returns the positive integer residue of the division a / b. So if **b = 2**, then **Modulus will always return 0 for even numbers** as all even values divide by 2 with no residue. **All odd numbers return 1**.

So by implementing the is_even-check you can call this function with all chosen random values and just count how often the functions returns True.